# How can pass default value for a textarea on UI Form component Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, ui-form

Is there a way to supply a dynamic default value for textarea field on a UI form?

I have a situation where the default value may change. In this case I was thinking the value could be stored in a file that could be updated by hand when needed. I would then use a class to retrieve the file contents to use as the default value of textarea field when a new record is shown. If the value was updated it would need to be saved and the updated value shown when editing the record.

Thoughts on how to handle this requirement?

Comment: yes, there is a way.

Comment: Please share how to do this